# Laravel - Use function in blade

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, helper

I'm beginning to build an app using Laravel, and one of the challenges I'm now facing is that throughout my blade views, i need to show a bunch of different bootstrap modals. Because of this, i believe it would be a better approach to create some sort of helper method that takes a few parameters to define how the modal should look. But im currently not sure what is best practice of doing this. Am i even allowed to use such a helper method in a view?

How would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper file and then define methods which can be used globally, including the views. But in your case the ideal scenario would be to use a partial and then to include the partial with different parameters to change the properties. This would work exactly like a method, but cleaner and more aligned with views. This should help you, the sub-views are called partials.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views

Comment: Thanks ! I wasn't even aware of sub-views, but this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You can still process any data using the PHP tags (`<?php echo 'hi'; ?>`), or even using the complete namespace of the file and then call the desired function, like `{{ \Carbon\Carbon::today() }}`